# Where the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure

Tags: c#, wmi

I need to get hdd info, and I want to use WMI.

example from msdn

```
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
...
string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
string className = "Win32_LogicalDisk";

CimInstance myDrive = new CimInstance(className, Namespace);
```

I'm using `Visual Studio 2015`. I've created a `console application` in solution for testing WMI. There is no Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, how to add it?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402447/querying-the-size-of-a-drive-on-a-remote-server-is-giving-me-a-not-found-error) shows the code for a remote server.  You can just remove the `ConnectionOptions` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added a reference to `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll`? (As specified at the top of the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.management.infrastructure.ciminstance(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Comment: FYI: On Win 10 and VS2015 that DLL is found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WMI\v1.0 courtesy of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8ae2a4f-e1f6-4b6e-a286-edda5ab0ed77/where-is-microsoftmanagementinfrastructuredll-assembly?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: @Richard can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504401/error-with-microsoft-management-infrastructure-native-dll-in-setup-project