# Error with Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.dll in setup project?

Tags: .net, winforms, dll, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I have a windows application in which I have used below dll - 
`Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.dll`

Now when I create setup project and right click on **Application Folder > Add > Project Output**. It adds automatically some dlls that is being used in application. 
But it shows a red line below the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.dll`
and because of that I am unable to create my setup project.

What is the solution of this?

Thanks

Comment: If you hover over that red line, does it provide some detail in a tool-tip?  My guess is you're referencing a 32bit dll, but targeting 64bit.